# App Engine: Restrict application to an authorized set of users

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, authentication

Some time ago, reading the App Engine Cookbook, I found this recipe based on the Users API (Python): http://goo.gl/aQl45 But my question is: How do I create the Users Database? Where do I locate the "allowed users" list? I don't understand...

Can somebody explain me how to get that recipe working in an actual app?

Comment: Maybe you need to start from scratch with Google App Engine before attempting to do sth. which you don't understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the middle of the page you link to, right below "Attached Files", are links to the three files that make up the sample app. The `AuthorizedUser` table is defined at the top of `auth.py`. You don't need to create that table manually in the same way you would with a relational database. You create AuthorizedUser entities and save (put) them, and App Engine takes care of giving you the illusion that there's a schema and that you have a table named `AuthorizedUser`.

Re-read http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/datamodeling.html and note the bit that starts "A datastore entity has a key and a set of properties." That can take a while to sink in if you're as steeped in relational thinking as I was, but once you get it, App Engine gets a lot less mysterious.

Comment: Can you please give me a quick example on how to add an "Authorized User"? I read the datamodeling thing but still not getting it quite well, as I understand, I have to add Gmail adresses down the "class AuthorizedUser(db.Model)" part right? But wich is the correct method to do it? thanks.